# Bootstrap mobile menu not appearing

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Hello I'm using Bootstrap to create a website, however when I try to add the hamburger menu it doesn't appear when I bring the screen size down.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hello world</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#toggleMobileMenu" aria-controls="toggleMobileMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-lable="Toggle Navigation">
      <span class = "navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="toggleMobileMenu">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link link-dark" href="#">About us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link link-dark" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link link-dark" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link link-dark" href="#">Book</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Welcome. Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the `navbar-light` class which specifies the background for the toggle button. Add that to the nav element.

> Navbars require a wrapping .navbar with .navbar-expand{-sm|-md|-lg|-xl|-xxl} for responsive collapsing **and color scheme classes**.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/components/navbar/#how-it-works

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<nav class="navbar navbar-light navbar-expand-lg">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Hello world</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#toggleMobileMenu" aria-controls="toggleMobileMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-lable="Toggle Navigation">
      <span class = "navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="toggleMobileMenu">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link link-dark" href="#">About us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link link-dark" href="#">Pricing</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link link-dark" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link link-dark" href="#">Book</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```